# What is the representation induced by $Z(G)$?

Tags: representation-theory

If $G$ is a finite group, and we have a representation of the center $\varphi\colon Z(G)\to GL(V)$, what is the induced representation on $G$? I've seen it mentioned in places, but not its definition.

Comment: I think this might be helpful: http://mathoverflow.net/a/106750

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_representation